# Why can't I exit the for cycle when the condition becomes false?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, cycle

I want the cycle to end when "0 00 00" is typed by the user. Here's the code:

```
main()
{
    int i, o[128], m[256], s[256];
    for(i = 0; o[i] != 0 && m[i] != 00 && s[i] != 00; i++)
        scanf("%d %d %d", &o[i], &m[i], &s[i]);
    printf("ok\n");
}
```

but the only way for it to end is by typing some characters.

Comment: Do you actually want to *store* the numbers in the 3 arrays, until this string is met? Not really clear ...

Comment: A do-while loop seemed to be more appropriate here.

Comment: i also tried your code but it is endless and code is also improper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is currently written, `i` is incremented **before** the condition is checked, so every time you're just checking for **indeterminate values**, which exhibits undefined behavior.

Use a do-while to ensure that the loop is executed at least once, while giving you more control:

```
i = -1; // Note the -1 here!
do{
    i++;
    scanf("%d %d %d", &o[i], &m[i], &s[i]);
} while (o[i] != 0 && m[i] != 0 && s[i] != 0);
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Why did you gave i the value of -1 instead of zero?

Comment: @user8852293 Because it gets incremented for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand sequencing of operations in the `for` loop to figure out the answer:

1. The initialization operation is performed, i.e. `i=0`
2. The condition is checked prior to entering the loop. Here is your first problem, becaise `o[]`, `m[]`, and `s[]` are not initialized.
3. Loop body is executed
4. `i++` is performed
5. The control is passed to step 2

Note that the condition in step 2 is always "ahead" of the loop body, checking elements that have not been initialized yet.

In situations like this it is better to end the loop from inside with a `break` statement, like this:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != 128 ; i++) { // Preserve the boundaries of o[128]
    scanf("%d %d %d", &o[i], &m[i], &s[i]);
    if (o[i] == 0 && m[i] == 0 && s[i] == 0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, in our course we can't use some statements like break or switch. Can you suggest me a way to store a number sequences in the arrays until "0 00 00" is met?

Comment: @user8852293 You can't detect the difference between end-user entering zero and two zeros, but you can detect `0 0 0`

Comment: I tried with a do-while and with single zeros https://pastebin.com/4cAFanuB but the result is the same

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several some problems:

- A `for` loop checks its condition **before** executing its body. In the first round you will check uninitialized variables. Use a `do ... while()` loop instead or initialize your arrays.
- You cannot parse the input as integer and the check for double zeros. If you want to do this, you have to parse this part of the input as string.
- You should check the return value of `scanf` to detect errors.

Comment: The purpose of the cycle is to store the numbers in the array until the 0 00 00 sequence is met, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

In case you are focred to use a `for`-loop and to rely on its condition to break it, you might solve this issue like this:

```
int main(void)
{
  int o[128 + 1] = {-1}, m[256 + 1] = {-1}, s[256 + 1] = {-1};

  for(size_t i = 1; /* Use size_t to index arrays */
    i < (128 + 1) && o[i-1] != 0 && m[i-1] != 0 && s[i-1] != 0; 
    i++) {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &o[i], &m[i], &s[i]);
  }

  puts("ok");
}
```

Please note the values at the arrays' position `0` are not read, but nailed down to `-1`.

If your code relies on `0`-based indexing you could trick this the following way:

```
int main(void)
{
  int oa[128 + 1] = {-1}, ma[256 + 1] = {-1}, sa[256 + 1] = {-1};
  int *o = oa + 1, *m = ma + 1, *s = sa + 1;

  for(size_t i = 0; /* Use size_t to index arrays */
    i < 128 && o[i-1] != 0 && m[i-1] != 0 && s[i-1] != 0; 
    i++) {
    scanf("%d %d %d", &o[i], &m[i], &s[i]);
  }

  puts("ok");
}
```

---

A much nicer solution however would be:

```
int main(void)
{
  int o[128], m[256], s[256];

  {
    ssize_t i = -1; /* If ssize_t isn't available use any signed integer wide enough. */
    do {
      ++i;
      scanf("%d %d %d", &o[i], &m[i], &s[i]);
    } while (i < 128 && o[i] != 0 && m[i] != 0 && s[i]);
  }

  puts("ok");
}
```

Comment: I tried the same solution as you with the do-while https://pastebin.com/6RxYLALH, but both yours and mine don't work

Comment: It's an endless cycle which doesn't stop when the user types 0 0 0

Comment: @user8852293: Fixed.